# Extruding straight down

Tags: extrude

I'm new to blender and I don't even seem to be able to extrude my faces straight down. I'm creating the base mesh for a shirt, but I keep extruding faces at different angles. Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Immediately after typing <kbd>E</kbd> (extrude), **type <kbd>Z</kbd> twice**: first to override the default direction (along the faces' normal), then to constrain the extrusion along the *Z* axis.

[image]

<sup>*(<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, move, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Note "along global Z" on the bottom bar)*</sup>

---

To add on this: you can constrain to an axis - X, Y or Z - also the other familiar operations <kbd>G</kbd> (move), <kbd>R</kbd> (rotate) and <kbd>S</kbd> (scale).

Similarly, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> constrains the transformation to *all axes except Z*.

Finally, selecting an axis twice means that the axis local to the object's internal coordinates is used, rather than the global one.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a really frustrating learning process, but this certainly helps me a step further!

Comment: Note that pressing Z twice will only transform along the Local axis if that is the transform orientation chosen in the 3D view header.